# Como adicionar classe quando adicionar arquivo

Tags: javascript

Quero adicionar um ícone de ok quando a pessoa adicionar uma foto no formulário, para mostrar a ela que a foto foi adicionada, o problema é que eu tenho uma imagem que devo seguir e então o nome do arquivo não aparece, quero facilitar o usuário para ele saber que a foto foi adicionada com sucesso e ele pode enviar o formulário.

```
<p>Selecione sua FOTO</p>
   <label for="photo">
   <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" style="filter:alpha(opacity=0); -moz-opacity:0; opacity:0;">
   <p class="icon-ok" id="iconeOk"></p>


<script>
$(function(){
if($("input:file")!=null){
        $('.icone-ok').addClass();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que, além dele não adicionar classe nenhuma no `p`, ele só roda uma vez, durante o carregamento da página.

Você precisa observar a mudança do elemento. O seu Javascript deve ser algo dessa forma:

```
$("input:file").on('change', function() {
  $("#iconeOk").addClass("icon-ok")
})
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cimegoya/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: +1 Cabe relembrar que no HTML o elemento `#iconeOk` deve inicialmente estar **sem** a classe `icon-ok` (ou: cada vez que o formulário for resetado - se aplicável - essa classe deve iniciar ausente).

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda.